# Python TypeError: module object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x

```
from nsepy import get_history
import datetime as date
import pdb
import talib

watchlist = ['ACC', 'VEDL']

for name in watchlist:

    df = get_history(symbol=name, start=date(2020,1,1), end=date.today())


    if df.empty:
        continue

    df['MA50'] = talib.MA(df['Close'], timeperiod=50, matype=0) 
    df['MA200'] = talib.MA(df['Close'], timeperiod=200, matype=0)

    MA50 = df.iloc[-1]['MA50']
    MA200 = df.iloc[-1]['MA200']

    if (MA50 > MA200):
        print(name, 'BUY')

    elif (MA50 < MA200):
        Print(name, 'SELL')

    else:
        print(name, 'IGNORE')
```

Comment: A more popular way to abbreviate the module is `import datetime as dt`. Its also popular to just import the classes you want, like `from datetime import date` (that's how the module's doc does it).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding:

```
import datetime as date
```

This imports the `datetime` *module,* renaming it `date` in the current context.

However, that module has a `date` *class* inside it, with a constructor for a date, which is probably what you wanted. Ditto for the `today()` member function.

Both of these are part of the `datetime.date` class, not part of the `datetime` module (renamed as `date`).

It's likely you want to do this instead:

```
from datetime import date
```

This will bring the `date` *class* into you current context, rather than the `datetime` module *renamed* as `date`.